# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: User disabled the feature

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, google-one-tap

I am making an app using Jetpack and Kotlin, I implemented Google oneTap signIn using Firebase. It was working properly, but once I pressed the back button on the sign in popup. That popup screen never showed again.
I tried many things like clearing my Google services storage and dialing *#*#66382723#*#* I also waited more than a day. But still, nothing is working

My logcat is throwing this exception

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: User disabled the feature.
```

I have gone through the Google document, several times. But still no clue.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 0):

The following error:

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: User disabled the feature.

Is thrown when a user cancels several prompts in a row. That's the reason why the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap) mentions that:

> It's important to implement your own rate limiting of One Tap sign-in prompts. If you don't, and a user cancels several prompts in a row, the One Tap client will not prompt the user for the next 24 hours.

In the code example, you can see that is specified to use a `REQ_ONE_TAP` which is set to `2`. In my opinion, this number can be considered a very small number for the retries, but to avoid such situations I recommend you implement your own rate limiting of One Tap sign-in prompts. So in your case, I'm afraid that you have to wait 24 hours until you can see the One Tap sign-in prompts again.

> I tried many things like clearing my Google Services storage, dialing ##66382723##

I personally didn't try that but I think it would be more helpful to clear the Google Play services app storage.

**P.S.** Please also note that [One Tap for Android will be deprecated soon](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials). So I recommend you try to implement [Credential Manager with Sign in with Google](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-manager).

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I just tried and when the user cancels several prompts the message is "Error 16: Caller has been temporarily blocked due to too many canceled sign-in prompts" but not the same message the original question. I'm suffering from the 'User disabled the feature' message too. It's only for some users and can't find the reason even though users have third party sing in prompt active.